# Diagonal difference

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I beginner to programming while I was coding Diagonal difference I came up with this approach,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int j = 0;
    int a[][] = new int[n][n];
    int count1 = 0; int count2 = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++){
        for(int a_j = 0;a_j < n;a_j++){
       
            a[a_i][j] = in.nextInt();
        
    }}
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        count1+=a[i][j];
        System.out.println(count1);
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    for(int i = n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        count2+=a[i][j];
        System.out.println(count2);
        j++;
    }
    result = Math.abs(count1 - count2);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Input**
*3

11  2  4

4   5  6

10  8  -12*
**Expected Output** 15
**My Output** 16

Comment: In your first loop, you are using j instead of a_j. Not sure if that's intentional but it's what I noticed.

Comment: Note that reusing variables (like you are with `j`) is often a bad idea, as demonstrated here. Declare variables in the *tightest possible scope*; declaring a variable has no inherent cost. You can declare (and update) multiple variables in a for loop (provided they are of the same type), so `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i<n; i++, j++)` is better for your second loop (or just use `i` in place of `j`, since they are equal), and `for(int i = n-1, j=0;i>=0;i--, j++)` for the third loop. (Remember to remove the `j++` from the body, though).

Comment: Taken from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference

Comment: @Flaom thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AndyTurner sure I will take that in mind. Thank you so much!

Comment: In your second for-loop, with a_j as the variable, you don't use it, but rather you use a[a_i][j]..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why so much work arounds ? 
You need a really minimal code :

```
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    count1+=a[i][i];
    count2+=a[i][n-1-i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to develop on Frank's answer, you don't actually need the array:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
    int v = in.nextInt();
    count1 += (i == j) ? v : 0;
    count2 += (i + j == n-1) ? v : 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java the solution would be

```
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        l+=a[i][i];
        r+=a[i][n-1-i];
    }
    result = abs(l-r);
```

For those who look how to do a same in python, here is how :

```
def diagonalDifference(a):
    l = sum(a[i][i] for i in range(len(a)))
    r = sum(a[i][len(a)-1-i] for i in range(len(a)))
    return (abs(r- l))
```

Comment: while this isn't very much code i find this incredibly unreadable

Comment: So what it could be then, if it's not a code? l stand for left, r for right r+= means r =r+. It's just a way to create a short code bro. Once u right a[i][i] it helps u to reach the diagonal left side. The trick here is in a[i][n-1-i] that allows you to reach the diagonal from the other side. I hope it's more comprehensible now. If u need any explanation feel free to ask :).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Javascript. I use forEach for readability. You can do it very similarly in Java.

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
    let length = arr.length-1;
    let leftDiag = 0;
    let rightDiag = 0;


    arr.forEach((item, outerIndex) => {
        item.forEach((innerItem, innerIndex) => {
            if (outerIndex === innerIndex) {
                leftDiag = leftDiag + innerItem;
            }
            if (length - outerIndex === innerIndex) {
                rightDiag = rightDiag + innerItem;
            }
        });
    });

    return Math.abs(leftDiag - rightDiag);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {

    int leftSum=0, rightSum=0;
    int i=-1;
    List <Integer> inner;
    Iterator<List<Integer>> list = arr.iterator();
    while (list.hasNext()){
        inner=list.next();
        i++;
        leftSum += inner.get(i);
        rightSum += inner.get(inner.size()-1-i);           
            
    }

    return Math.abs(leftSum-rightSum); 

}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    
    ListIterator<List<Integer>> itr = arr.listIterator();
    int i = 0,k=arr.size();
    int sumdia1=0 , sumdia2=0;
    List <Integer> inner;
    System.out.println(" k ::: "+k);
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
             inner = itr.next();
             k--;
            sumdia1= sumdia1 + inner.get(i);
            sumdia2= sumdia2+ inner.get(k);
            i++;
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a solution to the problem? An edit to this answer would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Java for Diagonal Difference Hackerank.

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    int primaryDiagnal = 0;
    int secDiagnal = 0;
    int diff;

    for(int i= 0; i<arr.get(0).size(); i++){
        primaryDiagnal += arr.get(i).get(i);
    }

    int col = arr.get(0).size() - 1;
    for(int i= 0; i<arr.get(0).size(); i++){
        secDiagnal += arr.get(i).get(col);
        col--;
    }

    diff = primaryDiagnal - secDiagnal;
    return Math.abs(diff);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for size/2 traversing approach. This might look intimidating but once you understand you will love its brilliance.

```
int i=arr.Count/2,j=i,sum=0;
        if(arr.Count%2 != 0){
           i--;
           j++; 
        }else{
            i--;
        }
        for(;i>=0;i--,j++){
        sum += arr[i].ElementAt(i)+arr[j].ElementAt(j)-arr[i].ElementAt(j)-arr[j].ElementAt(i);
        }
        return Math.Abs(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int leftD=0,rightD=0;
int size=arr.size();
int i=0;
for(List<Integer> lst : arr){
   leftD+=lst.get(i);
   rightD+=lst.get(size-i-1);
   i++;
}

int result=leftD-rightD;
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score -1):

```
int k=0;
int l=0;
int m;
int z=arr.length;
int s=arr.length-1;
for(int i=0;i<z;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<z;j++) {
        if(i==j){
            k=k+arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    l=l+arr[i][s];   
    s--;
}
if(l>k) {
    m=l-k;
} else {
    m=k-l;
}
return m;
```